# MS Access DBA CurrentDB() best practices in custom class

Tags: ms-access, vba

My custom class uses QueryDefs and Recordsets throughout. Usually in every method I need a QueryDef or Recordset I provide a variable for CurrentDB()

Is it acceptable to set db=currentDB() in the class Initialize sub and set it to nothing in the terminate sub?

What are the pros and cons for doing this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are after @HansUp here. Because I don't understand, I have likely not run into this before. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i have understood, you would like to access the currentdb() just once in your class to increase performance.

basically if you call currentdb() MS Access refreshes its collections and gives you the object. Calling currentdb many times could force the application to refresh for no reason. Which will delay your performance.

what you can do is to have global functions to retrieve the currentdb object.

create a module and try this functions:

```
private mMY_DB as dao.database

Public Function FN_GET_CRR_DB() As DAO.Database
    If (mMY_DB Is Nothing) Then Set mMY_DB = CurrentDb
    Set FN_GET_CRR_DB = mMY_DB
End Function
```

now instead currentdb you can use the fn_get_crr_db throughout your entire application. What it does is to access the Access object and saves it in a private variable for your use. once the variable is lost it refreshes it by calling currentdb once.

This could increase your dao performance.

Comment: So if I understand your answer @krish km, by setting CurrentDB several times, I am taking a performance hit. By calling it once objects are not refreshed, therefore things should perform much faster. I like your global function idea. I might have to see how I can incorporate that into my solutions.